# In XSD 1.0 - How to realize an xs:choice inside of an xs:all?

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to specify an XML schema that does not enforce ordering but includes a choice requirement. What is considered the "best practices" way of doing this?

For example, suppose I want the following to both be valid:

```
<foo>
  <bar>3</bar>
  <baz>tree</baz>
  <blort>
    <location>somewhere</location>
    <elevation>2000ft</elevation>
    <zing>1234567</zing>
  </blort>
</foo>
```

and

```
<foo>
  <baz>tree</baz>
  <blort>
    <elevation>2000ft</elevation>
    <location>somewhere</location>
    <bling>
      <name>A name</name>
      <number>7</number>
    </bling>
  </blort>
  <bar>3</bar>
</foo>
```

With the general "English description" rules being something along the lines of: "You have to include a bar, a baz, and a blort in any order. The blort must include a location, an elevation, and exactly one of either a bling or a zing, in any order."

I want to parse this in a validating parser that uses XSD 1.0. My first naive attempt was this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    targetNamespace="http://my.url/Foo"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://my.url/Foo"
    xmlns:mstns="http://my.url/Foo"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

<xs:complexType name="bling">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="number" type="xs:decimal"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="blort">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="elevation" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="zing" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="bling" type="mstns:bling"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="foo">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:decimal"/>
    <xs:element name="baz" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="blort" type="mstns:blort"/>
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="foo" type="mstns:foo"/>

</xs:schema>
```

But of course, that doesn't work. You can't put a "choice" inside of an "all".

I have not been able to find a way to express in XSD what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **substitutionGroup** approach.

This involves replacing an `xs:choice` using the `substitutionGroup` attribute. So, in your case, the `complexType` named "bling" has to be converted into a separate element named `bling` with the substitutionGroup `distinctIng`

```
<xs:element name="bling" substitutionGroup="distinctIng">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="number" type="xs:decimal"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

to make it part of the `substitutionGroup="distinctIng"`. Now you can put all the other (in this case: one) elements into the same `substitutionGroup` named , for example, `distinctIng`:

```
<xs:element name="distinctIng" />  <!-- abstract base element -->
<xs:element name="zing"  substitutionGroup="distinctIng" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="bling" substitutionGroup="distinctIng">
  ... (code from above) ...
</xs:element>
```

The only thing that remains to be done now is referring to the base element with

```
<xs:element ref="distinctIng" />
```

which, in this example, is the whole `xs:choice` replacing code:

```
<xs:complexType name="blort">
  <xs:all>
    <xs:element name="location" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="elevation" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element ref ="distinctIng" />  <!-- Replaced xs:choice by the above -->
  </xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: That's a good start, zx485! Now, if only there was a way to make that work for multiple repetitions of an element name (within the complexType) but with different types for that element. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: Your not an "Angel"("Engel") at all. You totally changed your question with a different requirement. If you have additional requirements not thematised in your original question. please ask a new one.

Comment: Yes, I did kind of "change" the question, @zx485. In fact my original statement of the question was incomplete. However, without knowing about substitutionGroup (I'm new to anything but the most rudimentary XML), I could not have known that. Are you offering to answer my "new" question if I post it as a new one?

Comment: The `substitutionGroup` approach is an answer to your original problem. I answered that as good as I could. But I do not know if I could answer your _new_ question as well. Others may do better than me, so I cannot give you that guarantee. Substantially changing a question after an answer has been given is against StackOverflow's rules, probably due to the following reason: At first, there is a question about, e.g., a null PTR in JavaScript. After this questions has been answered (several times!?), the tags of the question are changed to be about a `null` PTR in C. What now... Do you get it?

Comment: Yeah, I get it. And as I've said, you did well on addressing my original (incorrect) statement of the problem. Mea culpa...

Comment: Just ask a new question. It doesn't do harm to anybody ;-) If I could, I will be happy to answer it...